# ?radio=on on URL after form submit - How to turn it off?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm creating a form using reactjs and I have a radio input element. After submit and redirecting to another page at the end of the url there is a ?radio=on at the end which I don't want there.

http://localhost:3000/FormSubmit?radio=on

```
    return(
      <form action='/FormSubmit' id='form' onInvalid={handleEmptyDescription}>
        <div className="vertical-space">
          <label>Description </label>
          <textarea id='descr' type='text'
          value={description}
           onChange={handleDescriptionChange}
           maxLength='25'
           required/>
           <span> {wordCounter}/255</span>
        </div>
        <div>
        <label>Send confirmation</label>
        <input  type='radio' name='radio' required />
        <span>YES</span>
        <input  type='radio' name='radio' required />
        <span>NO</span>
        </div>
        <div className="vertical-space">
          <label>VAT </label>
          <select value={vat} onChange={handleVatChange} required>
            <option value="" disabled defaultValue >Choose VAT</option>
            <option value="1.19">19%</option>
            <option value="1.21">21%</option>
            <option value="1.23">23%</option>
            <option value="1.25">25%</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="vertical-space">
          <label>Price netto EUR </label>
          <input id='netto' pattern="\d+((\.|,)\d+)?" disabled={nettoDisabled} type='text'
          value={netto}
          onChange = {handleNettoChange}
          onKeyUp = {handleWrongInput}
          required/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span id='wrongInput' className='hiddenMessage messageStyle'> Please, input number</span>
        </div>
        <div className="vertical-space">
          <label>Price brutto EUR </label>
          <input id='brutto' value={brutto} disabled type='text'/>
        </div>
        <button onClick={handleSubmit} type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `method="post"` attribute on form tag to post data and prevent showing parameters in url